# convert this function c# encryption and decryption to Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

welcome everybody
I moved from xamarin to Flutter
I encountered some problems
Including encryption and decryption
How can I convert this function to Dart/Flutter?
This function is required to communicate with the api
Thank you everyone

```
    public static string encryp(string x, string encrypt)//function
    {
        try
        {

            string y = x;
            byte[] etext = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(y);
            string Code = encrypt;
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider mdhash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] keyarray = mdhash.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Code));
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tds = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            tds.Key = keyarray;
            tds.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            tds.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            ICryptoTransform itransform = tds.CreateEncryptor();
            byte[] result = itransform.TransformFinalBlock(etext, 0, etext.Length);
            string encryptresult = Convert.ToBase64String(result);
            return encryptresult.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (ex.Message==null ?"": ex.Message);
        }
    }


    public static string decrypt(string x, string keyai)
    {
        try
        {
            string y = x.Replace("\0", null);
            byte[] etext = Convert.FromBase64String(y);
            string key = keyai;
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider mdhash = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] keyarray = mdhash.ComputeHash(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tds = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            tds.Key = keyarray;
            tds.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            tds.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            ICryptoTransform itransform = tds.CreateDecryptor();
            byte[] result = itransform.TransformFinalBlock(etext, 0, etext.Length);
            string dencryptresult = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
            return dencryptresult.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return (ex.Message==null ?"": ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

update
I wrote this code on Flutter

```
     import 'package:dart_des/dart_des.dart' as des3;

     String encryptDataE(String _plainText, String _key) {
     var bytes = new List<int>.from(utf8.encode(_plainText));
     var key = md5.convert(utf8.encode(_key)).bytes; //The key is any letters
     des3.DES3 mDes3CBC = des3.DES3(
     key: key,
     mode: des3.DESMode.ECB,
     paddingType: des3.DESPaddingType.PKCS7,
     );
     final encrypted = mDes3CBC.encrypt(bytes);
     String value = base64Encode(encrypted);
     return value;
    }

    String decryptDataD(String _plainText, String _key) {
    String plainText = _plainText.replaceAll("\0", null);
    var bytes = base64.decode(plainText);
    var key = md5.convert(utf8.encode(_key)).bytes; //The key is any letters
    des3.DES3 mDes3CBC = des3.DES3(
    key: key,
    mode: des3.DESMode.ECB,
    paddingType: des3.DESPaddingType.PKCS7,
    );
    final decrypt= mDes3CBC.decrypt(bytes);
    String value = utf8.decode(decrypt);
    return value;
   }
```

After experimenting with encryption and decoding, this works now
One point left, how can this be achieved?

```
  //string y = x.Replace("\0", null);//c#
  String plainText = _plainText.replaceAll("\0", null); //I tried with this and it gets an error
```

Comment: Utf8 and base64 encoding is built into `dart:convert`, MD5 is available in `package:crypto` and there's a 3DES implementation with ECB mode here: https://pub.dev/packages/dart_des Put those together in some Dart code, and update this question or ask another with any issues.

Comment: Thank you sir, I have updated the question

Comment: After experimenting with encryption and decoding, this works now One point left, how can this be achieved?       String plainText = _plainText.replaceAll("\0", null);

Comment: I din't understand what the c# is trying to do. Replace any characters with codepoint 0 with `null`? But what is a null code point?? Maybe it wants nothing, in which case try replacing them with `''` in Dart. This sounds like a perfect topic for a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/c-to-dart-transpiler/9p5bnfrsmq00) tool: *"Use the tool e.g. for porting your Xamarin/UWP project to Flutter"*

Otherwise, there is a pretty easy Flutter Encrypt package [here](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt)

```
//Package example
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

void main() {
  final plainText = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';
  final key = Key.fromUtf8('my 32 length key................');
  final iv = IV.fromLength(16);

  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));

  final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);

  print(decrypted); // Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
  print(encrypted.base64); // R4PxiU3h8YoIRqVowBXm36ZcCeNeZ4s1OvVBTfFlZRdmohQqOpPQqD1YecJeZMAop/hZ4OxqgC1WtwvX/hP9mw==
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this tool
It will save a lot of effort

Comment: Except _encrypt_ doesn't support DES...